# How to send data using webrequest class method?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, webrequest, sendmessage

In my application I send data to a PHP server. I got code from the msdn website.

```
void SendPost()
    {
        var url = "http://www.nuatransmedia.com/ncampaign/mailserver/mail1.php";

        // Create the web request object
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Start the request
        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);    
    }

    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        // Create the post data
        // Demo POST data 
        string postData = "Hello";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Add the post data to the web request
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
    }

    void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {    
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response;

            // End the get response operation
            response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            response.Close();

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            // Error treatment
            // ...
        }
    }` void SendPost()
    {
        var url = "http://www.nuatransmedia.com/ncampaign/mailserver/mail1.php";

        // Create the web request object
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Start the request
        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);    
    }

    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        // Create the post data
        // Demo POST data 
        string postData = "Hello";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Add the post data to the web request
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
    }

    void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {    
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response;

            // End the get response operation
            response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            response.Close();

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            // Error treatment
            // ...
        }
    }
```

I got mail. But the body messages not show in my mail. Where did I make a mistake? In my PHP code I use `postData` variable to get my message.

Comment: Try reading post data using http://www.codediesel.com/php/reading-raw-post-data-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

For simpler HTTP usage the classes at http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http might help you...

These classes help to HTTP POST files (access via `$_FILES["..."]`). Also there is a `RawData` property (`byte[]`) to set the data directly.

(also GZIP, own timeout, and more is supported)

Comment: http://www.dot4pro.com/posting-data-to-the-web-from-windows-phone-7.html-this web helped me a lot